# Fetch last subfolder name in full path to file

Tags: bash

I'm listing files. From the paths

```
/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/ak_riks1.gml
/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/ak_riks2.gml
```

I need to extract the name of the last subfolder, which is `tempgis` and `folder`

But:

```
for f in $(find /home/bera/Desktop -name '*.gml'); do dir="$(basename $f)" ; echo $dir; done
```

Is printing the filenames and not the last folders:

```
ak_riks1.gml
ak_riks2.gml
```

(From the accepted answer this is my complete command: `for f in $(find /home/bera/Desktop -name '*.gml'); do dir=$(basename $(dirname $f)); echo $dir; done` )

Comment: No need to use a `for loop` with command substitution, see why https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting just the name of the last folder could be achieved with

```sh
FILE=/some/path/to/file.txt
# dirname $FILE          => "/some/path/to"
# basename /some/path/to => "to"
echo "$(basename $(dirname "$FILE"))" # prints to
```